# Error: "object dict can't be used in 'await' expression" in Telegram Bot using python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, dictionary, async-await, openai-api, python-telegram-bot

I am developing a Telegram bot using the python-telegram-bot framework and asyncio for asynchronous programming. My goal is to create a feature where users can click an 'AI' button in the Telegram bot to ask questions, which are then answered by ChatGPT via an integration I'm attempting to implement.

Here's the part of the code where I handle messages from users who are in an "AI session". When a user sends a message, I check if they are in an AI session and, if so, send their message to ChatGPT for a response. However, I keep encountering the error "object dict can't be used in 'await' expression", and I'm not sure why. I've been stuck on this issue for 5 hours.

main.py FILE:

```
from typing import Final
from telegram import Update, KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes
from gpt_integration import get_gpt_response

TOKEN: Final = 'xxxx'
BOT_USERNAME: Final = '@xxxx'

users_in_ai_session = {}


async def start_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    button_list = [
        [KeyboardButton("/AI"),
         KeyboardButton("/price")]
    ]
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        button_list, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    await update.message.reply_text("Welcome message...", reply_markup=reply_markup)


async def search_price_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text("Please enter the contract address:")


async def AI_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    user_id = update.effective_user.id
    users_in_ai_session[user_id] = True
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "You're now chatting with AI. Go ahead, ask me anything!")


async def handle_message(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    user_id = update.effective_user.id
    if users_in_ai_session.get(user_id, False):
        user_input = update.message.text
        # Implement this function based on your GPT model
        response = await get_gpt_response(user_input)
        await update.message.reply_text(response)
    else:
        # Handle non-AI messages
        print("Error")


async def error(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    print(f'Update {update} caused error {context.error}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting bot')
    app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))
    # 'AI' is meant to trigger AI interaction
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('AI', AI_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('price', search_price_command))
    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, handle_message))
    app.add_error_handler(error)
    print('Fetching updates...')
    app.run_polling()
```

gpt_integration.py FILE:

```
import httpx


async def get_gpt_response(message_text):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.post(
            'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions',
            headers={
                'Authorization': 'xxxx'
            },
            json={
                'model': 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
                'prompt': message_text,
                'max_tokens': 50
            },
        )
    data = await response.json()
    return data['choices'][0]['text'].strip()
```

1. Ensuring that all async functions are properly awaited.
2. Checking that get_gpt_response returns an awaitable object.
3. Reviewing Python's asyncio documentation for potential misuse of the await keyword.
   I suspect the issue might be related to how I'm using the await keyword or possibly a misunderstanding of how to properly use dictionaries in asynchronous functions. Could someone please help me understand what's causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `response.json()` returns a dict, which you don't need to `await` with. You can try to change `data = await response.json()` to `data = response.json()` instead.